# Get number of pages in a pdf using a cmd batch file

Tags: pdf, batch-file, cmd

I can see there are a lot of questions for getting the number of pages in a a pdf with C, PHP and others but am wondering with a batch file or cmd is there a simple way of getting the number of pages?

Comment: define "batch file". you can write a PHP script and put the execution of the script in a text file, save it as .bat and its also called a batch file. You need to specify whether external tools are allowed or just simply pure cmd.exe.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Using [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/):

`pdftk my.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages`

does the trick.

Comment: Substitute `grep` by `findstr` and you even run on Windows without having to install more than pdftk.

Comment: Combine the responses above `pdftk my.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'` and you just get the number.

Comment: Another way to just get the number is to use awk to print the second column. `pdftk my.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: PDFtk requires Java runtime, which is quite a big dependency. Good to know about that.

Comment: With AWK, the use of grep is unnecessary, @Mehmet. `pdftk my.pdf dump_data | awk '/NumberOfPages/{print $2}'` Likewise, sed alone is enough. `pdftk my.pdf dump_data | sed '/NumberOfPages/!d;s/[^0-9]*//'`

Comment: If you want to summarize the number of pages of all of the pdf files in a directory just write: for f in *pdf; do pdftk $f dump_data ; done| awk '/NumberOfPages/ {sum+=$2; print $2} END {print "Summa: " sum}'

Comment: @ArpadHorvath Probably more powerful would be with find: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pdf" -exec sh -c "pdftk '{}' data_dump" \; | awk '/NumberOfPages/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 43):

Alternatively you can use the command, which returns only the number:

`pdfinfo "${PDFFILE}" | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'`

You will need the poppler package:

https://poppler.freedesktop.org/

Which can be installed using either homebrew / linuxbrew:

```
brew install poppler
```

or with `apt`:

```
sudo apt install poppler-utils
```

Comment: Actually, in Debian, the package is poppler-utils. Xpdf just uses the Poppler library and recommends poppler-utils.

Comment: To sum up the number of pages in all PDF files of a directory: `( for pdf in *.pdf ; do pdfinfo "$pdf" ; done ) | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//' | paste -sd+ | bc`

Comment: Quite amazingly on a 180page PDF. Your solution is faster than the qpdf one above.

`matt@mtbook:~/projects/booky% time ./booky-pdfinfo.sh 
real 0m0.129s
user 0m0.099s
sys 0m0.022s`

matt@mtbook:~/projects/booky% time ./booky-qpdf.sh 
real 0m0.039s
user 0m0.019s
sys 0m0.020s

Comment: This is a better answer. poppler-utils is more suitable even for server environment and is a supported ubuntu package.

Comment: The times you posted lead me to the exact opposite conclusion from the one you had drawn, @cavalcade. QPDF won, being 3× faster in real time, 5× in raw userspace processor time.

Comment: True @Palec. Maybe I switched the numbers around by mistake or got confused, but as written it does support opposite conclusion as you said. Weird

Answer (score 30):

[**QPDF**](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) is a **lightweight** alternative to PDFtk (requiring Java runtime) and pdfinfo (quite a dumb tool).

```
qpdf --show-npages file.pdf
```

It prints just the number of pages, needing no post-processing.

Packages for most Linux distributions exist, usually named just `qpdf`. Pages like Softpedia host [binaries for Windows](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/QPDF.shtml). The [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/qpdf/) can be downloaded from SourceForge, or from the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf).

---

The `--show-npages` option was added in a version after 4.1.0, in [commit 91367239fd55f7c4996ed6158405ea10573ae3cb](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/commit/91367239fd55f7c4996ed6158405ea10573ae3cb). To be compatible with **version 4.1.0 and earlier**, you can dump basic information about each page and count the pages. In Linux and OS X:

```
qpdf --show-pages file.pdf | grep -c ^page
```

On Windows, you should use `findstr` and `find` instead:

```
qpdf --show-pages file.pdf | findstr ^page | find /c /v ""
```

Comment: It appears to installed by default on my Ubuntu 16.10 installation! :D

Comment: If you want to summarize the number of pages of all of the pdf files in a directory just write: for f in *pdf; do printf "$f "; qpdf --show-npages $f ; done| awk '{sum+=$2; print $0} END {print "Summa " sum}'

Comment: Also appears to be installed by default on Manjaro, and contrary to currently higher-voted answers, does the job without needing piping to other commands

Answer (score 7):

Without any external tools (save the script bellow as `.bat`) :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off

cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"  %*

exit /b 0
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

   var args=WScript.Arguments;
   var filename=args.Item(0);
   var fSize=0;
   var inTag=false;
   var tempString="";
   var pages="";

   function getChars(fPath) {

        var ado = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
        ado.Type = 2;  // adTypeText = 2
        ado.CharSet = "iso-8859-1";
        ado.Open();
        ado.LoadFromFile(fPath);                     
        var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        fSize = (fs.getFile(fPath)).size;

        var fBytes = ado.ReadText(fSize);
        var fChars=fBytes.split('');
        ado.Close();
        return fChars;
   }


   function checkTag(tempString) {

    if (tempString.length == 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    if (tempString.toLowerCase().indexOf("/count") == -1) {
        return;
    }

    if (tempString.toLowerCase().indexOf("/type") == -1) {
        return;
    }

    if (tempString.toLowerCase().indexOf("/pages") == -1) {
        return;
    }

    if (tempString.toLowerCase().indexOf("/parent") > -1) {
        return;
    }


    var elements=tempString.split("/");
    for (i = 0;i < elements.length;i++) {

        if (elements[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("count") > -1) {
            pages=elements[i].split(" ")[1];

        }
    }
   }

   function getPages(fPath) {
        var fChars = getChars(fPath);

        for (i=0;i<fSize-1;i++) {

            if ( fChars[i] == "<" && fChars[i+1] == "<" ) {
                inTag = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (inTag && fChars[i] == "<") {
                continue;
            }

            if ( inTag && 
                 fChars[i] == ">" &&
                 fChars[i+1] == ">" ) {

                inTag = false;
                checkTag(tempString);
                if (pages != "" ) {
                    return;
                }

                tempString="";

            }

            if (inTag) {
                if (fChars[i] != '\n' && fChars[i] != '\r') {
                   tempString += fChars[i];
                }
            }

        }

   }

   getPages(filename);
   if (pages == "") {
     WScript.Echo("1");
   } else {
    WScript.Echo(pages);
   }
```

It takes the path to the `.pdf` file and simply prints the number of the pages.Not pretty fast as it reads the pdf symbol by symbol , but could be optimized.

Comment: How does this return the number of pages in the PDF file?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche   -  here's example `pdfpages.bat pdffile.pdf` ? Is there a problem?

Comment: Yes :) But my real question was, what in this code figures out how many pages there are? I'm trying to understand what does the counting here?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche This all becomes more obvious if you look at the raw byes of a .pdf  in a Hex editor (Hex workshop is a good one). Basically looking for something like the string: `<</Type/Pages/Count 21` getPages() scans the pdf bytes for "<<" tags and passes the read contents into checkTag(). checkTag() then splits the contents into elements using "/" as a separator and scans the element for the string "count", when finding that it then splits the element on space " " and returns index [1] i.e. the second value in the array in the example above 21

Comment: Actually, I've written a PDF renderer in my past so I know exactly how a PDF file looks like. I also know that this code will never work in real life as PDF files can contain many instances of the "<</Type/Pages/Count..." string that either are simply not used or do not reflect the real number of pages in the PDF document. This method is unreliable at best and should not be used.

Comment: This works well, but pretty slow for a document with hundred of pages.
I tried your script with 420 pages pdf, it correctly output 420, but it took several minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Because you asked for a "batch file" I have to assume you only want a Windows-based solution. But, just in case Mac OS X is an option, here something that could be useful. 
If you have the PDFs on a Mac, on a drive that has been indexed by Spotlight (the default), the following command will return the number of pages using no external dependencies:

```
mdls -name kMDItemNumberOfPages POSIX_PATH_OF_PDF_FILE
```

Source: [MacScripter.net - http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=32381](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=32381)

Comment: can confirm, works still for macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old post, yet still very much relevant, so I believe that there should be an answer which can tell how to get page count using "**poppler-0.68.0**" utility, in windows.

Navigate to bin folder and run **pdfinfo.exe** like - 
`C:\Temp\temp_folder\poppler-0.68.0\bin>pdfinfo.exe "C:\Temp\temp_folder\TT.pdf"`

[image: Code in action]

Comment: There is already [a highly-voted pdfinfo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10614490/2157640), but processing the output manually instead of using grep & sed might be a good idea sometimes and this screenshot helps with that. +1

Comment: Pre-built binary for Windows can be found here.
https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful for new users. In the new version of PDFtk tool (above 2.0), use below command to get the number of pages of a PDF file:

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data_annots output outputfile.txt
```

A new file will created at destination having content similar to below:

```
NumberOfPages: 6
```

Now read the file and manipulate the content as you want.

Answer (score -1):

To do it with VBA, open Excel, hit <kbd>ALT + F11</kbd> to open VBA

Insert Module, copy + paste the code below, save the module as a macro enabled workbook.

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute VBA code, a dialog box should appear; select the folder that contains the PDF's and the code will count the logical pages in each PDF, totals in column B - PDF name will populate in Column A.

```vba
Sub Test()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim xFileNum As Long
    Dim RegExp As Object

    ' Create a file dialog object
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    ' Display the file dialog and get the selected folder
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.pdf", vbDirectory)
        
        ' Set the range for data output
        Set xRg = Range("A1")

        ' Clear previous contents and set headers
        Range("A:B").ClearContents
        Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        xRg = "File Name"
        xRg.Offset(0, 1) = "Pages"

        I = 2 ' Start from row 2 for data
        
        ' Loop through each PDF file in the selected folder
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            ' Display file name in column A
            Cells(I, 1) = xFileName

            ' Initialize RegExp object to count pages
            Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            RegExp.Global = True
            RegExp.Pattern = "/Type\s/Page[^s]"

            ' Open the PDF file and read its content
            xFileNum = FreeFile
            Open (xFdItem & xFileName) For Binary As #xFileNum
                xStr = Space(LOF(xFileNum))
                Get #xFileNum, , xStr
            Close #xFileNum

            ' Count pages using RegExp and display in column B
            Cells(I, 2) = RegExp.Execute(xStr).Count

            I = I + 1 ' Move to the next row
            xFileName = Dir ' Get the next file
        Loop

        ' Autofit columns for better visibility
        Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This only works for some PDFs. It may count too many pages (e.g. in an edited PDF) or too few (e.g. in a PDF in which the page dictionaries are part of compressed object streams). For simple, freshly generated PDFs it may work, though.

Answer (score -2):

A simple way if ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick is installed:

```bash
   identify *.pdf | wc -l
```

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone wants an alternative using Excel and VBA:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5330-excel-vba-pdf-page-count.html

1. Open a worksheet where you want to get the Pdf files and page numbers.
2. Hold down the ALT + F11 keys, and it opens the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window.
3. Click Insert > Module, and paste the following macro in the Module Window.

> Sub Test() Dim I As Long Dim xRg As Range Dim xStr As String Dim xFd
> As FileDialog Dim xFdItem As Variant Dim xFileName As String Dim
> xFileNum As Long Dim RegExp As Object Set xFd =
> Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) If xFd.Show = -1
> Then xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
> xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & ".pdf", vbDirectory) Set xRg = Range("A1")
> Range("A:B").ClearContents Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True xRg = "File
> Name" xRg.Offset(0, 1) = "Pages" I = 2 xStr = "" Do While xFileName <>
> "" Cells(I, 1) = xFileName Set RegExp =
> CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp") RegExp.Global = True RegExp.Pattern =
> "/Type\s/Page[^s]" xFileNum = FreeFile Open (xFdItem & xFileName) For
> Binary As #xFileNum xStr = Space(LOF(xFileNum)) Get #xFileNum, , xStr
> Close #xFileNum Cells(I, 2) = RegExp.Execute(xStr).Count I = I + 1
> xFileName = Dir Loop Columns("A:B").AutoFit End If End Sub

Copy

4. After pasting the code, and then press F5 key to run this code, and a Browse window is popped out, please select the folder that contains the Pdf files you want to list and count page numbers,
5. And then, click OK button, all Pdf file names and page numbers are listed into the current worksheet

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).