# Batch file + cPDF to find number of pages in multiple PDFs

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, cmd

I am trying to automate a very specific task: checking a folder full of PDFs for any that have an odd number of pages. Each PDF is a section of a document and I want each section to start on the right page.

I chose cPDF as an easy PDF command-line tool and wrote the follow command line:

```
for %f in (*.pdf) do cpdf -pages %f"
```

That completed the immediate task today: I could look down the output in the command line window and see which file(s) had an odd number of pages. But I'm the only one in the office that will ever use this unless I can make it a double-click process that then shows a much more simple/legible output. So I thought I'd write a batch file:

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do cpdf -pages %%f >> ".\pages.txt"
```

was my first attempt, but it writes just the number of pages on one continuous line, so I can't read which file has how many pages.

How can I add the file name to the output and have each result be on a separate line? Or even better

```
Number of pages:
fileA.pdf 6
fileB.pdf 8
fileC.pdf 7
fileC.pdf 10
fileD.pdf 13
fileE.pdf 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This batch should output only files with odd page numbers:

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(Echo Number of pages:
 for %%f in (*.pdf) do For /F "delims=" %%p in ('cpdf -pages %%f') Do (
   Set /A rest=%%p %% 2
   If !rest! equ 1 Echo %%f %%p 
))> ".\pages.txt"
```

**Edit** inserted missing `)`
With the free version of cPDF you need to change the for command to:

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do For /F "skip=1 delims=" %%p in ('cpdf -pages %%f') Do (
```

To skip this sample output:

```
> cpdf -pages .\cpdfmanual.pdf
This demo is for evaluation only. http://www.coherentpdf.com/
70
```

**Edit2** According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672607/6811411) pdftk is a real free alternative:

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(Echo Number of pages:
 for %%f in (*.pdf) do For /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%p in (
   'pdftk %%f dump_data ^| findstr "NumberOfPages" '
 ) Do (
   Set /A rest=%%p %% 2
   If !rest! equ 1 Echo %%f %%p 
))> ".\pages.txt"
```

Comment: LotPings, thank you for the batch. When I run it, it does not create "pages.txt". The cmd window pops up temporarily, but then closes. I simply copy-pasted your code into a text file and renamed it "test.bat".

Comment: Thanks for feedback, there was a closing parenthesis missing. Changed above. Do you use the free version of cPDF? Then you need to insert a `skip=1` in front of `delims=`.